# Tomcat 7 Clustering

Tags: java, tomcat7, cluster-computing

Using Tomcat 7, I have created a two server cluster using the [SimpleTcpCluster shortcut](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cluster-howto.html#For_the_impatient) in the `<Engine>` container. Those server are talking correctly each other at startup and shutdown.

I have deployed a web-app named meteo-cluster.war, with `<distributable/>`. I have used the Web Application Manager to deploy the webapp on Server1.
On this computer, `http://localhost:8080/meteo-cluster/` works correctly.

Unfortunately, it's not deployed on Server2. Should it be automatic, or should I use also the web deployer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular deployment doesn't work that way. You'll need a [farm deployer](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/cluster-deployer.html) to do this automatically:

```
<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster">
          <Deployer className="org.apache.catalina.ha.deploy.FarmWarDeployer"
                    tempDir="/tmp/war-temp/"
                    deployDir="/opt/tomcat7/webapps/" 
                    watchDir="/tmp/war-listen/"
                    watchEnabled="true" />
</Cluster>
```

Also, this will only work in the `<Host>` container:

> Note: FarmWarDeployer can be configured at host level cluster only.